# Discover # or @ in a input

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

Is it possible with jQuery to discover when a user has entered the first character in a search box as <kbd>@</kbd> or <kbd>#</kbd> and then prompt an alert no matter what keyboard language or settings they have?

for instance, if I enter <kbd>@</kbd> into the searchbox I want it to prompt a message or perform my action.

```
​<input type='text' name='search' id='search' />​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

jQuery

```
$("#search").keydown(function(event) {
    alert(event.which);
});​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the [`keypress` event](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) reports a reliable value for `event.which`: http://jsfiddle.net/QDCvG/

```
$("#search").keypress(function(event) {
    // @ = 64, # = 35
    if ((this.value.length === 0 || this.selectionStart === 0)
     && (event.which === 64 || event.which === 35)) {
        // keypress fires before the field is populated
    }
});​
```

[`String.fromCharCode(event.which)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) can be used to get the typed character.

Comment: What if the user edits the field to insert a # at the beginning?

Comment: Good point. I would add an additional check, using `this.selectionStart`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test whether the *first* character in the input is one of those characters then don't test the character just typed, test the first character:

```
$("#search").on("blur", function() {
    if (/^[@#]/.test(this.value))
       alert("@ or # entered.");
});
```

Note that it would be better to do that on blur (or even on submit of the form) rather than on every keystroke both because that would be less annoying to the user and because it would cope with copy/paste or drag'n'drop.

Comment: `keydown, keypress` fires **before** the field is populated.

Answer (score 1):

You must change your event to bind `keyup`, it will fire event even when two keys are released. The `.charAt(0)` method will check the first character of your input box.

```
$("#search").keyup(function(event) {
     var curKey = $(this).val();

     if (curKey.charAt(0) == '@' || curKey.charAt(0) == '#')
     {
         alert('@ or # typed first!');
     }
});
```

LIVE : http://jsfiddle.net/yHcVH/